# Can we represent all objects in the universe in a small cube?

Tags: science-based, computers, brain, information

Imagine this. An alien culture needs the information of all objects that are present in the universe. Could a cube with an internal structure be constructed so that all objects of the universe can be somehow represented? I thought of dense, neuron-like structure with a huge number of connections between the neurons. If the connections have variable connection strengths you can represent a huge number of objects, like the brain has representations of zillions of whatevers.

Say the cube is 10x10x10=1000 cubic meters. It is used as a databank for future intergalactic internet via wormholes scattered through space to connect all regions of the universe. Information between all parts can be of this.

What about the feasibility of the cube?

At first sight this seems impossible. Then just think a bit deeper...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128236/discussion-on-question-by-deschele-schilder-can-we-represent-all-objects-in-the).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox

Answer (score 4):

If you mean, "Could the cube contain all the information there is to know about all objects in the universe?", then clearly no. As Allan points out in a comment, the cube itself is in the universe, so the cube would have to contain all information that is contained in the cube, plus more for what is outside the cube. So we'd have to add the information that is not already in the cube. But then there is yet more information to record. We have an infinite recursion problem.

Even ignore the recursion problem, if it contains "all information" than it would have to record the exact position and composition of every atom. Even if you had highly advanced data storage techniques and could record everything there was to know about every atom on one atom, you'd still need as many atoms inside the cube as there are atoms in the universe. Even ignoring the cube itself, your cube would have to contain as much mass as exists in the entire rest of the universe.

If you mean something more like, "The cube contains a summary of information about everything in the universe. Not the exact position of every atom, but more general descriptions." Then the answer is clearly yes. At least if we assume that you summarize at a level that is within the memory capacity of the cube. In that sense I could store information about everything on the universe on one sheet of paper with a crayon: I just write "there's a big universe with stars and planets". There, I've described everything in the universe. Of course the more detail you want to record, the more memory capacity you need. The total amount you need depends on how much detail.

Comment: All objects, even all atoms trajectories can be represented in the cube. Like in my brain. If I shut my senses and have an eternnnal live than my brain can represent all features, objects and their trajectories, colors or whatever. These representations will exceed the number of atoms in the universe. So the cube can represent all objects.

Comment: I understand your answer though. A good answer! +1

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Having an eternal life to think about everything in the universe only helps if you assume that the universe remains completely static during this time, or that you are satisfied to fully know its state at one instant. Also, this assumes that you are satisfied to only know a subset of the facts at any given time. If you learn a quadrillion facts but then your brain's capacity is maxed out and you have to forget things to learn more, then you can't know everything all at once. And if you just assume that your brain has the capacity to know everything all at once, ...

Comment: ... then you've just assumed away the problem. And almost certainly falsely: the brain is of finite size so presumably has finite capacity.

Comment: Obviously you cant think of all at once. My brain has the possibility though, in principle, to think about just as many things as there are in the universe. Every different object csn cause a different sensation. Therr can rage even a storm in my head. Litterally every different path of a particle can be represented. Or every collection of particles with associated motions.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder "My brain has the possibility though, in principle, to think about just as many things as there are in the universe." No it really doesn't, your brain has finite limits, the only way it can think about things beyond that limit is by overwriting information about previous things.

Comment: "My brain has the possibility though, in principle, to think about just as many things as there are in the universe. " No, it doesn't. There are more atoms in the universe than there are in your brain. Your brain has a finite capacity, and that capacity is much smaller than the universe. Take a much, much smaller problem: tell me the names of everyone in the world. You can't, of course, because your brain does not have the capacity to remember 7 billion names all at once. You might know a few dozen, maybe a few hundred, But not billions.

Comment: You can speculate that if you tried really hard and trained yourself right or whatever that perhaps you could remember 7 billion names. But there is zero evidence that this is true. No human being has ever managed anything remotely resembling this.

Answer (score 1):

### Hard No

Every object would require modeling every atom which would require at minimum , that is at the theoretical limit of data compression, an equal number of atoms. So you need another universe to make a perfect model of the universe.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128240/discussion-on-answer-by-john-can-we-represent-all-objects-in-the-universe-in-a-s).

Answer (score 0):

**No, brains don’t solve the problem**

You mention in multiple comments that you can imagine the whole universe given infinite time. Let’s assume that is true, you now have a separate problem, how do you remember all that? To do so you need to store that information somewhere. The greatest information density possible is defined by the [Bekenstein bound](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound) if you can’t fit the information in that bound that you can’t store all the information even if you can process it.

As far as neurons, putting connections between neurons doesn’t make more data. 5 neurons can store 10 bits of info if each nueron has one bit weight between them, but to do that you need to have 10 bits and 5 nuerons. The 5 nuerons has the same amount of possible combinations, so it has the same amount of data capacity, but takes more space due to the nueron.

Answer (score 0):

This actually does have a scientific answer: the [Bekenstein bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound) which the article describes as "*... the upper limit on the ... information I, that can be contained within a given finite region of space which has a finite amount of energy—or conversely, the maximal amount of information required to perfectly describe a given physical system down to the quantum level. It implies that the information of a physical system, or the information necessary to perfectly describe that system, must be finite if the region of space and the energy are finite.*"

Conveniently, it also says: "*It happens that the Bekenstein–Hawking boundary entropy of three-dimensional black holes exactly saturates the bound*" or, translated to plain English, a black hole is perfectly at the Bekestein limit.  No representation of all of the information (in the information theoretic sense) contained within a black hole can be represented by anything with less mass plus volume than the black hole itself.

Therefore, *even if we exclude the cube itself the universe*, since the cube clearly does have less mass plus volume than even one black hole (or it wouldn't be usable or even safe to approach without being crushed by gravity), it cannot possibly contain enough information to represent the state of one black hole, let alone the entire universe. QED.

Bonus commentary:

How much information could we represent in the querent's hypothetical 10×10×10 meter cube?  The Physics SE posting at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2281/maximum-theoretical-data-density , suggests that the maximum possible limit is on the order of ~10^66 bits per cubic centimeter, so the cube can at most contain ~10^75 bits regardless of what type of matter or energy it's composed of or how dense it is.  That's 10^62 terabytes of data.

Well, that sounds like a lot of data so the next question that arises is how much of the universe could we represent with that much data?  Going back to the Wikipedia article on the Bekenstein bound, we find an approximate formula of I = 2.576 × 10^43 bits/(kg × m) × mass (in kg) × radius (in meters).  If we plug in the mass and radius and mass) of the earth (6.371 × 10^6 m and 5.972 × 10^24 kg respectively), we get a result of about 9.8 × 10^74 bits, which is within spitting distance of the 10^75 bits that the querent's 10×10×10 meter cube can store.  So the answer is: around one Earth and maybe a bit of its surroundings.

(It should however be noted that this isn't particularly useful since the Earth isn't static and so the information contained in the cube is out of date immediately after the cube is created.)

Answer (score -3):

Say the cube contains 10exp14 neurons that are all connected to the other neurons. There is a staggering amount of possible paths in this network. Starting from the first neuron you can reach 10exp14-1 other neurons. From these neurons you can reach 10exp14-2 neurons (assuming a forward path). From these there are 10exp14-3 in reach. So the number of paths on which a signal (or various parallel signals, though this is a bit smaller) can travel is:

10exp14x10exp14-1x10exp14-3x10exp14-4x...x10exp14-100x...x10exp14-1000000x...x4x3x2x1

That is a 1 with 10exp(10exp14) zeros!

The number of elementary particles is "only" 10exp83. That is peanuts in comparison with the number I have shown.

That means the cube is possible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128241/discussion-on-answer-by-deschele-schilder-can-we-represent-all-objects-in-the-un).